# Making a brushless servo using Hall sensors

Tags: otherservos, brushless-motor, esc

I'd like to assemble a prototype of brushless servo system using a RC brushless motor (heavily geared down), a sensored Electronic Speed Controller for RC motors, and a microcontroller to do the PID control.

[image: Brushless motor and sensored ESC]

I'd add three Hall sensors around the motor, and feed those signals into the ESC and the microcontroller. The MCU will run a PID controller, and output an RC servo compatible PWM signal to the ESC.

Question: Is this likely to work, or will I find that the ESC is trying to be clever? I have one RC car which only switches into reverse if you double pulse the reverse signal.

(Note, the reason I'm trying to get this working using an off-the-shelf ESC, rather than designing my own proper one is that development time is *much* more expensive than parts cost at the moment).

Comment: Can you provide datasheets for your components?  My gut feel here is as you suggest that the ESC's input is going to be very low bandwidth and limit your control.  What's your application?  What sort of performance are you looking for?  Why not buy an off-the-shelf brushless servo controller?

Comment: @GuySirton - Sadly, these kind of RC components often don't have datasheets. They're just listed on [e-bay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Tyrannosaurus-120A-Sensored-Brushless-BEC-ESC-for-1-10-1-8-Car-Competition-/321200666650?pt=UK_ToysGames_RadioControlled_JN&hash=item4ac90d381a) with their specs.

Comment: @GuySirton - The reason I decided against an off-the-shelf solution is that I need a very good power:weight ratio. That's the reason I'm using brushless motors. Off-the-shelf controllers tend to be massive, and I loose all the weight advantage.

Comment: How about something like this: http://www.elmomc.com/products/Tweeter-digital-servo-drive.htm

Comment: @GuySirton - Now why didn't Google show me that before? I've only spent a week searching for brushless servo drives! Those  look pretty cool, but I'd need the [Whistle](http://www.elmomc.com/products/whistle-digital-servo-drive-main.htm) which is a little on the heavy side for my application.

Comment: ESCs for sensorless brushless motors have a whole fandango that they go through to get the motor started, and it really only works well when there's not much torque on the motor.  If you must go this route, I'd look at a sensored brushless car motor (I seem them on Craig's List all the time) and select a matching ESC that lets you go into reverse immediately.  Keep in mind that a big part of the reason that model airplane brushless hardware is so compact is because they expect -- and depend on -- a constant airflow to keep things cool.

Comment: @TimWescott - I *am* talking about sensored motors. That's why I said I'd add 3 Hall sensors.

Comment: @TimWescott - Also, I'm not too worried about overheating. A plane needs constant airflow to keep cool because it's running at high power for extended periods. My servo application isn't, so it should be all right.